# springboot with integration framework fails on missing brave.Tracer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

Spring boot + integration framework fails on:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: brave.Tracer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
```

tried to add:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.brave</groupId>
        <artifactId>brave</artifactId>
        <version>5.13.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please, share more stack trace and probably would be grate to have a small project from you to reproduce. On the other hand, there is nothing to do with Brave in Spring Integration, neither Spring Boot. This is Spring Cloud matter. So, you indeed have some Sleuth dependency, but missing Brave or so. Please, try to follow their samples: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/tree/3.1.x/spring-cloud-sleuth-samples

Comment: Yeah, it came from parent , sorry.